# set overflow hidden only to parent div

Tags: html, css

I have sidebar menu. `#menu li a`  have a  `transform: scale(1.1)` 
I want to scale text and Icons inside `li` and keep it width same 
I tried `overflow:hidden` but sub menu is not showing either

any help?

```css
.page-container {
    min-width: 1260px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.content {
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 600px;
    display: block;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed {
    padding-right: 65px;
    transition: all 100ms linear;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back {
    padding-right: 280px;
    transition: all 100ms linear;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .sidebar-menu {
    width: 65px;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .sidebar-menu {
    width: 280px;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .sidebar-icon {
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .sidebar-icon {
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .logo {
    padding: 21px;
    height: 136px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .logo {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 21px;
    height: 136px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed #logo {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back #logo {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed #menu span {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 50ms linear;
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    right:10px;

}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back #menu span {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
    top: 17px;
    right: 75px;
    position: absolute;

}

.sidebar-menu {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #303641;
    color: #aaabae;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}

#menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

#menu li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(69, 74, 84, 0.7);
    padding: 0;

}

#menu li ul {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0px;
}

a:hover {
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 200ms;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #333944;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(1.3);

}

#menu li.active > a {
    background-color: #2b303a;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#menu ul li {
    background-color: #2b303a;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    right: 100%;
    top: -1px;
    background-color: #2b303a;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(69, 74, 84, 0.7);
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

#menu li li ul {
    right: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: -1px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
}

#menu li li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

#menu .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.logo {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 21px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 136px;
}

.sidebar-icon {
    position: relative;
    right: -6px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #454a54;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container sidebar-collapsed">
    <div class="sidebar-menu">
       
        <div style="border-top:1px solid rgba(69, 74, 84, 0.7)"></div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li id="menu-home"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>first</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i><span class="fa fa-angle-left"
                                                                     style="float: left; position:unset;"></span><span>second</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i> Pinterest</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
         
              

                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-history"></i><span>blog</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i><span>settings</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p25kkgyn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inserted a container between you `a` tags that show the background and the text/icon content. I used a `div` because your `span`s are already so styled.

I added the container to first and second only, just to demonstrate the sublist still shows.

look for your `a:hover` selector changed to `a:hover .expandable` in the styles.

```css
div.expandable {
    display: inline-block;
}

.page-container {
    min-width: 1260px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.content {
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 600px;
    display: block;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed {
    padding-right: 65px;
    transition: all 100ms linear;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back {
    padding-right: 280px;
    transition: all 100ms linear;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .sidebar-menu {
    width: 65px;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .sidebar-menu {
    width: 280px;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .sidebar-icon {
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .sidebar-icon {
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .logo {
    padding: 21px;
    height: 136px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .logo {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 21px;
    height: 136px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed #logo {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back #logo {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed #menu span {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 50ms linear;
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    right:10px;

}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back #menu span {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
    top: 17px;
    right: 75px;
    position: absolute;

}

.sidebar-menu {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #303641;
    color: #aaabae;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}

#menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

#menu li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(69, 74, 84, 0.7);
    padding: 0;

}

#menu li ul {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0px;
}

a:hover {
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 200ms;
}

#menu li a:hover .expandable {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #333944;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(1.3);

}

#menu li.active > a {
    background-color: #2b303a;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#menu ul li {
    background-color: #2b303a;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    right: 100%;
    top: -1px;
    background-color: #2b303a;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(69, 74, 84, 0.7);
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

#menu li li ul {
    right: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: -1px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
}

#menu li li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

#menu .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.logo {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 21px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 136px;
}

.sidebar-icon {
    position: relative;
    right: -6px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #454a54;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container sidebar-collapsed">
    <div class="sidebar-menu">
       
        <div style="border-top:1px solid rgba(69, 74, 84, 0.7)"></div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li id="menu-home"><a href="#"><div class="expandable"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>first</span></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div class="expandable"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i><span class="fa fa-angle-left"
                                                                     style="float: left; position:unset;"></span><span>second</span></div></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i> Pinterest</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
         
              

                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-history"></i><span>blog</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i><span>settings</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.page-container {
    min-width: 1260px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.content {
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 600px;
    display: block;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed {
    padding-right: 65px;
    transition: all 100ms linear;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back {
    padding-right: 280px;
    transition: all 100ms linear;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .sidebar-menu {
    width: 65px;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .sidebar-menu {
    width: 280px;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .sidebar-icon {
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .sidebar-icon {
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .logo {
    padding: 21px;
    height: 136px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .logo {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 21px;
    height: 136px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed #logo {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back #logo {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed #menu span {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 50ms linear;
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    right:10px;

}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back #menu span {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
    top: 17px;
    right: 75px;
    position: absolute;

}

.sidebar-menu {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #303641;
    color: #aaabae;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}

#menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(69, 74, 84, 0.7);
    padding: 0;

}

#menu li ul {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0px;
}

a:hover {
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 200ms;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #333944;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(1.3);

}

#menu li.active > a {
    background-color: #2b303a;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#menu ul li {
    background-color: #2b303a;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    right: 100%;
    top: -1px;
    background-color: #2b303a;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(69, 74, 84, 0.7);
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

#menu li li ul {
    right: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: -1px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
}

#menu li li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

#menu .fa {
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.logo {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 21px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 136px;
}

.sidebar-icon {
    position: relative;
    right: -6px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #454a54;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container sidebar-collapsed">
    <div class="sidebar-menu">
       
        <div style="border-top:1px solid rgba(69, 74, 84, 0.7)"></div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li id="menu-home"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>first</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i><span class="fa fa-angle-left"
                                                                     style="float: left; position:unset;"></span><span>second</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i> Pinterest</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
         
              

                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-history"></i><span>blog</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i><span>settings</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

```
#menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: with hidden overflow second li ul is hidden